# Readiness Check failed in magento 2

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp, magento2

I installed a Magento 2 and now try to insall an extension but its Readiness Check failed.

[image]

I have used below configurations:

```
Operating systems: Windows 7 with 64-bit
PHP tool: XAMPP 5.6.15
Apache Version: 2.4
MySQL Version: 5.6.26-74.0
PHP Version 5.6.15
Installed PHP extensions:
bc-math, curl, gd, intl, mbstring, mcrypt, mhash, openssl, PDO/MySQL, SimpleXML, soap, xml, xsl, zip, json
PHP settings: memory_limit=512M
```

Please suggest How can I resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you please let me know why this question is down voted?

Comment: Hopefully [this page](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/trouble/readiness/tshoot_rc_cron.html) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, the cron doesn't seem to be running. That means that Magento can't detect the PHP version and so on. So please make sure that the cron ist running, then you should be able to pass the Readiness Check ;-).

Just read the text below "Check Cron Scripts" ...